# ANTLR grammar for indented nested list

Tags: antlr

I wonder is it possible to create a grammar for hierarchical indented list like this one:

```
→ a
→ b
  → b1
    → b11
    → b12
  → b2
  → b3
→ c
```

which textual representation can be simplified to:

```
a
b
>b1
>>b11
>>b12
>b2
>b3
c
```

The main problem is that I don't see a way to preserve and use level of nesting. What I tried was:

```
grammar test;
list: (item)+ ;
item: NAME NL (sublist[1])*;
sublist[int n]: (subitem[$n])+;
subitem[int n] locals [int i=1;]: ({$i <= $n}? ID {$i++;})+ NAME NL (sublist[$n+1])*;
NAME: [a-z0-9]+;
ID: '>';
NL: '\r' ? '\n';
WS : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

i.e. with ANTLR variables and semantic predicates, but on what I was hoping - `({semantic-predicate}? TERM )+` — simply doesn't work like I was expected (it triggers only needed amount of times - to consume the stream) making incorrect results.

Specifically, having `>>b12` on the input, when `subitem` is called with `n=3`, this part:

`({$i <= $n}? ID {$i++;})+`

instead of 'expecting' three '>'-chars, triggers on the second.

Ideas?

Comment: You can look up how it is done in Python grammar. (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4)  The main idea is to re-write tokens to synthesize IDENT /  DEDENT pairs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I know that lists which already have indent/dedent (like HTML ones) is much easier to parse. But I didn't want to use preprocessing of any kind outside ANTLR, so rewriting with its means seems very interesting to me.